# How to implement the recursive call in a quicksort program

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I am trying to implement the recursive call to run a quicksort algorithm. However, it does not seem to work. What might be the problem with the code below? Obviously there are solutions available online, however, I would like to see what I am doing wrong in the code that I have written. This will help me better understand how to use recursive calls.

The code is able to do the first partition using the last index "6"

```
def quicksort(list):
if len(list)>1:
    pivot=list[int(len(list)-1)]
    Left=[]
    Right=[]
    i=0

    while i<int(len(list)):
        if list[i]<pivot:
             Left.append(list[i])
        elif list[i]>pivot:
            Right.append(list[i])
        i=i+1

    if len(Left)>1:
        quicksort(Left)
    if len(Right)>1:
        quicksort(Right)

    Left.append(pivot)
    combined=Left+Right
    return combined
```

`list=[9, 7, 5, 11, 12, 2, 14, 3, 10, 6]
print(quicksort(list))`

output:
    `[5, 2, 3, 6, 9, 7, 11, 12, 14, 10]`

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also, ["it's not working" is not a helpful problem statement.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 0):

You call `quicksort` recursively and then discard the results:

```
    if len(Left)>1:
        quicksort(Left)
    if len(Right)>1:
        quicksort(Right)

    Left.append(pivot)
    combined=Left+Right
    return combined
```

Maybe `Left = quicksort(Left)`?